# awk '{print $<number>}' but without knowing <number> before hand

Tags: sql, shell, awk

Printing a specific column per line using pipe to awk is fine.

But how do I do it if I do not know which column it is, except I have to get the column who's first row matches something.

Example.

```
Title1  Title2  TargetTitle  Title3
   x      y         z           a
   b      c         d           e
```

The above table, I want to filter out only:
z
d

BUT, two problems
1) I don't know exactly the column number 
2) I don't want first row (not a big deal, I can just sed lines 2 to $).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate this "column who's first row matches something"?

Comment: What tis your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your output using awk like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                 if ($i=="b"||$i=="d") $i=""; printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF)?ORS:OFS}}' file
x   y   z   a
    c       e
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter out one column, you could use something like this:

```
awk -v title="TargetTitle" 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i==title) col=i }
NR>1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (i!=col) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

Output:

```
x y a
b c e
```

If you want to add more space between each column in the output, you can change the value of the `OFS` variable or change the first format specifier from `%s` to `%4s`, for example.

If you want to only print one column, you can do something like this:

```
awk -v title="TargetTitle" 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i==title) col=i }
NR>1 { print $col }' file
```

Output:

```
z
d
```